# PyQt5 get pos of another widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to map one widgets `pos()` (A) to another widget (B), so that B can do some work based on A's position. I have `WidgetA` that gets `WidgetB` pos, these widgets can have different parenting hierarchy:

```
Global
+--- Window
     +--- WidgetA
     +--- WidgetB

Global
+--- Window
     +--- Sub
     |    +--- Sub
     |         +--- WidgetB
     |
     +--- WidgetA

Global
+--- Window
|    +--- WidgetB
|
+--- WidgetA
```

etc.

I have tried to translate `B`'s position to a relative position on `A`' via (Both widgets share same parent):

```
WidgetB.setGeometry(150, 150, 100, 100)

                                                                 # expected vs result
WidgetA.mapFromGlobal(WidgetB.mapToGlobal(WidgetB.pos()))        # 150, 150    125, 200
WidgetA.mapFrom(WidgetA.parent, WidgetB.pos())                   # 150, 150    -25, 50
WidgetA.parent.mapFromGlobal(WidgetB.mapToGlobal(WidgetB.pos())) # 150, 150    300, 300
```

What is the correct way to do this mapping? I cannot seem to wrap it correctly.

Code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore

import sys

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, Parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.WidgetA = QWidget(self)
        self.WidgetA.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.WidgetA.setObjectName("WidgetA")

        self.WidgetA.setGeometry(400, 400, 100, 100)

        self.WidgetB = QWidget(self)
        self.WidgetB.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.WidgetB.setObjectName("WidgetB")

        self.WidgetB.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
        #WidgetA {
            background-color: red;
        }
        #WidgetB {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        """)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print(self.WidgetB.pos())
        print(self.WidgetA.pos())

        print(self.WidgetA.mapFromGlobal(self.WidgetB.mapToGlobal(self.WidgetB.pos())))
        print(self.WidgetA.mapFrom(self, self.WidgetB.pos()))
        print(self.mapFromGlobal(self.WidgetB.mapToGlobal(self.WidgetB.pos())))




if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    screen = Window()
    screen.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint()
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(400, 400)
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(-400, -400)
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(-400, -400)
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint()
```

I would expect to get `(0, 0)` since that is what `WidgetB` is set to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position of a widget is relative to the parent, it is not a position with respect to the screen, so in your example you should obtain `(400, 400)`.

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop):

> **pos : QPoint**
>
> This property holds **the position of the widget within its parent**
>   widget
>
> If the widget is a window, the position is that of the widget on the
>   desktop, including its frame.
>
> When changing the position, the widget, if visible, receives a move
>   event (moveEvent()) immediately. If the widget is not currently
>   visible, it is guaranteed to receive an event before it is shown.
>
> By default, this property contains a position that refers to the
>   origin.

There are some methods that seem to work but it is because you have established the position of the parent widget in `(0, 0)`, if you change it, it will fail.

Considering that you want the position of A with respect to B, the solution is as follows:

1. Obtain the position of Widget B with respect to the screen using the following:

   ```
   gp = self.WidgetB.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0))
   ```

it is passed `(0, 0)` because `mapToGlobal` requires the position with respect to the widget that uses the function, in your case the position of `WidgetB` with respect to `WidgetB` is `(0, 0)`.

2. Then the global position respect the `WidgetA` is mapped:

   ```
   b_a = self.WidgetA.mapFromGlobal(gp)
   ```

So the following example shows the operation of my solution:

```
import sys

from random import randint

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.WidgetA = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.WidgetA.resize(100, 100)
        self.WidgetA.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.WidgetA.setObjectName("WidgetA")

        self.WidgetB = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.WidgetB.resize(100, 100)
        self.WidgetB.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.WidgetB.setObjectName("WidgetB")

        self.posA = QtCore.QPoint(randint(0, self.width()-100), randint(0, self.height()-100))
        self.posB = QtCore.QPoint(randint(0, self.width()), randint(0, self.height()))

        self.WidgetA.move(self.posA)
        self.WidgetB.move(self.posB)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
        #WidgetA {
            background-color: red;
        }
        #WidgetB {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        """)

        self.WidgetA.installEventFilter(self)
        self.WidgetB.installEventFilter(self)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj in (self.WidgetA, self.WidgetB, self) and event.type() in (QtCore.QEvent.Resize, QtCore.QEvent.Move) : 

            gp = self.WidgetB.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0))
            b_a = self.WidgetA.mapFromGlobal(gp)
            print(b_a, self.posB -self.posA)
            assert(b_a == (self.posB -self.posA))

        return QtWidgets.QWidget.eventFilter(self, obj, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I always assumed that when I called `WidgetB.mapFromGlobal()` that it did it based on its position to its parent. `WidgetB.mapFromGlobal(QPoint(0, 0))` works perfectly.

Comment: @Drew docs: *Translates the widget coordinate pos to global screen coordinates. For example, mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)) would give the global coordinates of the top-left pixel of the widget.*, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal